# How to fetch the "All Mail" label from the gmail api?

Tags: gmail, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

So when mail is archived in gmail, the message can be left without any labels attached.

In this case, the message is still accessible in the "All Mail" view.

I am using the gmail API, and I would like to represent `All Mail` as a label.

Is it possible to fetch the `All Mail` label via the API? I'm looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get) and I'm not seeing anything.

Also, in case it helps, I am using the [google php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to interact with this API.

Comment: Once you archive the message even though it goes to "all mail", you cannot retrieve it giving this as label name in the query of messages.list. You can give -in:inbox from:XXXX@gmail.com in messages.list, retrieve this particular archived email. Hope this explains your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a `All Mail`-label in your application, and under the hood simply call [User.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with no labelIds given. That way you would get all the messages, disregarding labels completely.

Comment: Ah, I figured this would be what I'd have to do.